# how calculate local holder exponent in digital signal in matlab

Tags: matlab

The formula of Hölder local exponent is as follows:

```
 |f(x)-f(y)| < C*|x-y|^a
```

if *f(x)* doesn't have a derivative and it is continuous in the same local area centered at x0.

```
a(x0)=sup(ln|f(x)-f(y)|)/ln|x-y|
```

How can I calculate the local Holder exponent ***a*** in digital signal with DWT discret wavelet in matlab ?

Note: The local and point-wise Hölder is not same.

Comment: [Cross-posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2282247/algorithm-to-calculate-local-h%C3%B6lder-exponent-for-discrete-signal-in-matlab)  and several others that have since been deleted.